# Using Expanded or Flexible and ListTile overflow still 32 pixels over

Tags: flutter, dart

No matter if I use Wrap instead of Row. Flexible or Expanded don't work either?

[image]

```
return ListTile(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 0.0),
      dense: true,
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(icon),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top: 0.0, bottom: 0.0),
            child: Expanded(
              child: Text(
                googleplace.address,
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      onTap: onTap,
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListTile already has a way to use an icon and a text without wrapping it in a Row widget

```
return ListTile(
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  dense: true,
  leading: Icon(icon), // put your icon here
  title: Text(
    googleplace.address,
    maxLines: 1,
    softWrap: true,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  ),
  onTap: onTap,
);
```

Also in your code if you want the row to detect the expandable correctly you should use first the Expandable Widget and then the padding

```
Expanded(
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top: 0.0, bottom: 0.0),
    child: Text(
      googleplace.address,
      maxLines: 1,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    ),
  )
),
```

But I would recommend the first option, ListTile already has trailing and leading inbuilt widgets to help you with what you want